# What is the default logging level for Java

Tags: java, log4j

I have recently started learning logging levels and going deep into the logging frameworks. For a simple java program, say Hello World which is the starter for any programming language. Can I ask what is the default logging level set for this.

```
public class A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("Hello stackoverflow");
  }
}
```

For this basic program what is the default logging level set, where it was set. In log4j we have configuration file like log4j.xml or log4j.properties. For this program what is the reference, can we change its logging level.

Comment: erm ... `println()` has nothing to do with logging levels or logging frameworks. It prints to `stdout`

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println` just prints to `STDOUT`. It doesn't have anything to do with logging. Logging levels are controlled by logging frameworks like `log4j`.

Comment: off by one, reversing.  poor question, people are bashing this person pretty hard lol.

Answer (score -2):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class A{
  public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(A.class);
  public static void main(String[] args){
    logger.*pickOne*("Hello stackoverflow");
  }
}
```

I think it's 'debug' in your question. if you wish to change from debug, add this into the log4j xml file:

```
<category name="your.package.name">
        <priority value="WARN"/>
    </category>
```

Comment: read @Vivin Paliath 's answer first